# How Do I Redirect My Frontend React Application From External API Call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, frontend, single-page-application

I am building a mini project and I am using a Payment Processor called Paystack. Typically, when a payment is initiated by the user, the payment processor generates a unique link for that current payment transaction. All the payment processor requests are set up in the Backend, I am using NodeJS and Express basically. Now my current issue is redirecting the frontend to the payment gateway using the generated link. The code for handling that looks like this basically.

```
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer ApiKey",
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${API_URL}/payment/paystack/pay/${ref}`,
        config
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

The result of `res` is the link generated. How do I make my frontend goto the generated link?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it an external link or internal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the React app link, use React history.

For React class component:

```
this.props.history.push(url);
```

For React hook:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...
const history = useHistory();
...
history.push(url);
```

If it's an external link, you should not use React stuff. Just use `window.location`:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign your link to `window.location` and let your browser handle the rest.

```
window.location = link;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call `window.open()` and pass the link as an argument. For example

```
 window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
```

Or you could use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)